# Grub консоль вместо загрузчика

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub

При старте системы Ubuntu 16.04 загружается консоль grub.
Ну и соответственно я провожу ряд действий для загрузки ОС.

```
set root=(hdX,X)
linux vmlinuzX...
initrd initrxX...
boot
```

После этого, система корректно загружается. 
Однако, после ребута мне опять приходится совершать эти действия для загрузки.
Прошу помочь советом, как пофиксить эту ситуацию. :)

Comment: update-grub2 %% grub-install /dev/sdX

Comment: а вообще, такие вопросы лучше задавать на Ask Ubuntu

Comment: @Danatela  Я не понял смыла "%%". Может быть Вы имели в виду "&&"?

Comment: "а вообще, такие вопросы лучше задавать на Ask Ubuntu" - вопрос слишком нубский или с чем связан сей совет?

Comment: @Danatela`$ sudo update-grub && grub-install /dev/sda1
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub
Searching for default file ... found: /boot/grub/default
Testing for an existing GRUB menu.lst file ... found: /boot/grub/menu.lst
Searching for splash image ... none found, skipping ...
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
Found kernel: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
Updating /boot/grub/menu.lst ... done
Probing devices to guess BI`

Comment: и да: "update-grub2 %% grub-install /dev/sdX" - не помогло :)